# response must be a factor Svylor

Tags: r, linear-regression

Hi: I would appreciate any help in going around this problem I have been stuck on. My help searches have not been helpful.

I am running a svy  logistic regression outcome(0/1):

```
lhpo<-svyolr(polco~hsageir + gender + dose, design, 
    method = c("logistic"),data=kids)
```

and I am getting this error message  : response must be a factor

I have tried avenues like as.factors etc but no luck. The model works fine with glm (with family=binomial)

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

YA

Answer (score 1):

Try this modification:

```
lhpo<-svyolr(as.factor(polco)~hsageir + gender + dose, design, method = c("logistic"),data=kids)
```

NB: it's spelled `as.factor`, not `as.factors` as you stated in your question.

If this doesn't work, please provide a reproducible sample to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the reference manual](http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/html/svyolr.html), the *svyolr* function "fits cumulative link models: proportional odds, probit, complementary log-log, and cauchit."

Moreover, in the Arguments section, the manual says: "the response must be a factor with at least three levels".

Setting *method* for "logistic" will give you a proportional odds logistic regression model for response variables with 3 or more levels. If you want a regular logistic model, you should use *svyglm* with the *family* argument set to "quasibinomial".